# How to find the quotient of two numbers in a list - python

Tags: python

I am a begineer in python and i am trying to create a basic calculator.So what i did was to ask the user for input and put it in a list called operations.

```
operations = []
```

I performed all the operations sucessfully except with division.Beacause i couldn't preform the division operation in the list ,I created two variabes then place all of them in the list operations.Since they where input from users i could not use the append fuction.So i did this:

```
a = int()
b = int()
operation = [a,b]
divide_result=a//b
print(f'Your result is{divide_result}')
```

I did not want to declare a function for this because i was going to use it once.
So after this code i got this error:

divide_result=a//b
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Comment: Maybe ```divide_result=a//b if b!=0 else "Undefined"```

Comment: You didn't specify any values when you called `int()`. With no arguments it just returns `0`. You should get `a` and `b` from the user.

Comment: Why couldn't you perform division in a list? How did you try to do it? How did you do multiplication (for example)?

Answer (score 1):

You initialized your variables to 0 by calling `int()`

Than you tried to divide by zero.

What you probably wanted to do was:

```
a = int(input("Enter dividend:"))
b = int(input("Enter divisor:"))

divide_result = a // b
print(f'Your result is{divide_result}')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that somehow your variable `b` got set to 0.

Here's my code and it works

`calc.py`

```
import sys

def main():
    a = input("please enter integer a: ")
    b = input("please enter integer b: ")

    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)

    if b == 0:
        print("cannot enter 0 for b. divide by 0 error")
        sys.exit(1)

    result = a/b
    print(f"{a}/{b} = {result}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
python3 calc.py
please enter integer a: 10
please enter integer b: 20
10/20 = 0.5
```

Comment: Well written code.